# Socket sample code in FreeBSD Kernel Module

Tags: sockets, kernel, freebsd

I need a simple example like an echo server as a FreeBSD kernel module (or syscall).
I have seen [OpenKETA](http://openketa.sourceforge.net/), but it has a large code, it's too difficult to understand and use it.
Is there a simple example?

Comment: How about this: http://www.paulgriffiths.net/program/c/echoserv.php or http://www.speakfreely.org/doc/echo.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish, and not to advertise, but based on the question, I'd suggest getting a copy of [Designing BSD Rootkits](http://nostarch.com/rootkits.htm) and [FreeBSD Device Drivers](http://nostarch.com/bsddrivers.htm). I've read both and I think they will help you.

Comment: I have both books, but they have nothing about sockets in kernel. BSD Rootkits book has an example of receiving icmp packet, but I need tcp or udp to send data. ICMP just sends network control packets.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to take a look at documentation for sosend(9) family of functions (man 9 sosend).  Those are the kernel routines to operate on sockets.